# Java jsch and remote file transfer

Tags: java, swt, jsch

I'm using `Jsch` to transfer an html file from a remote server to my local system, which I plan on showing in an `SWT` browser.  `com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp` provides a getter method that returns an `InputStream`.  I'm wondering if theres a way to translate that `InputStream` into a `URL` without writing the file contents out to disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom [Protocol Handler](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/protocolhandlers/), and then (in theory) anything that takes a URL object should be able to use the custom protocol to retrieve data. The protocol handler would then just encapsulate the JCraft code.